# Can't show Git history on OpenGrok on windows

Tags: git, window, opengrok

I have OpenGrok up and running with these:
Tomcat 9
Java 11
opengrok-1.5.11
ctags-p6.0.20230416.0-x64
Git
Git Repository

My problem is that I want OpenGrok will support History of git but it doesn't work.
The History ( and also Annotate ) are just text and not link and when I choose file and click on the H link I get error.

This is the index command I'm running:

```
"C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-11\bin\java" -Xmx1048m -jar C:\apps\opengrok-1.5.11\lib/opengrok.jar  -P -W C:\OpenGrok\run_update_SRC.xml -v -H -S -G --depth 8 -c C:\apps\ctags-p6.0.20230416.0-x64\ctags.exe -s "C:\OpenGrok_Sources\setup" -d "C:\opengrok\grokdata\SRC"
```

Any suggestions ?